# Python URL TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Tags: python, http, web, httprequest

I am trying to write a small web request program to get some of the popular Instagram users (this is python 3).

```
final_list = [];
for idx in range(1, 5, 1):
    url = "http://zymanga.com/millionplus/" + str(idx) + "f"; # idx is for page number
    print(url);
    headers = {...omitted header details...};
    req = urllib.request.Request(url, None, headers);
    with urllib.request.urlopen(req) as f:
        str = f.read().decode('utf-8');
    initial_list = re.findall(r'target=\"_blank\">([^<]+?)</a>,', str);
    for item in initial_list:
        final_list.append(item);
```

The first iteration works well (and I am able to get the users on the first page), however on the second iteration, I am encounting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\web_search.py", line 8, in <module>
    url = "http://zymanga.com/millionplus/" + str(idx) + "f";
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Could you please let me know what might caused the problem, tried to debug but couldn't resolved it. Thanks!

Comment: try `url = "http://zymanga.com/millionplus/".join(idx) + "f"`;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `str` as a variable at `str = f.read().decode('utf-8');`. In the next loop, the `str(idx)` is no longer the class `str` but the value from `f.read().decode('utf-8')`.

Never use the class types as variable names. Just to illustrate the mistake:

```
>>> str
<class 'str'>
>>> str(1)
'1'
>>> str = 'some string'
>>> str
'some string'
>>> str(1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out!

Answer (score 6):

You've redefined `str` within your loop so that it refers to the variable read from the response. Choose a different name.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out!

Answer (score 3):

```
str = f.read().decode('utf-8')
```

`str` is the contents of the file you read on the last pass through the loop. You are trying to call it like a function with `str(idx)` but it is not one.

Don't use the names of built-in functions for your own variables.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out!